# Cant´t access a WCF Service, that uses basicHttpBinding and hosted outside IIS, from other machine over a local network

Tags: web-services, wcf

I created a service with two endpoints, one for netHttpBinding and other for basicHttpBinding.

I am able to "Add Service Reference" from a Client Solution using both addresses (`net.tcp://localhost:8080/Whatever or http://localhost:8000/ProductsService/Service.svc`) from the same machine

But when trying to "Discover" the service **from another machine over the network**, I'm able to do it using the `net.tcp://localhost:8080/Whatever` address **but not with the `http://localhost:8000/ProductsService/Service.svc` address**

When I use the basicHttp one I get the error (http):

[image]

I tried to run netsh (running Comand Prompt as Administrator) as:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8000/ user=<Machine Name>\Username
```

and I get the following error:

```
Url reservation add failed, Error: 103
Cannot create a file when that file already exists
```

**What do I have to do to "Discover" (with Go of course) the service from another machine using the basicHttp endpoint?**

I'm using the ServiceHost type to "publish" the service, and the ServiceModel node (App.config) of the solution that defines the service is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to discover the service from its service address - you should really try to discover it from it's `mex` address.

Based on your configuration, you should be able to find the service at:

```
http://machineName:8000/ProductsService/mex
```

or even at

```
http://machineName:8000/ProductsService
```

**EDIT**

Firewall possibly blocking inbound connections.  Add firewall inbound rule on the service host to allow tcp connections on port 8000.

Comment: Hi, I tried both approaches, the base address and the mex endpoint address, and both failed. It keeps telling me that the service is unavailable or that there is no endpoint listening at the mex address. I uploaded the small project to https://onedrive.live.com/#cid=228822BB183339A9&id=228822BB183339A9!234. But if I use the nettcp endpoint, it works fine. I deleted the previous configuration of netsh and added it again, I successfully made the port 8000 reservation for the remote user, but it still doesn´t work. I remember that I tested it some days ago, and it worked, don´t know what happened

Comment: then it must be the firewall blocking inbound connection on the server host. add firewall inbound rule to allow tcp connections on port 8000.

Comment: Thank you YK1. That was it. Please write an answer to mark it please.

Comment: Alright, great. Edited answer to add firewall comment.